# Hide off-canvas-cart after clicked the "add to cart" button shortcode - Flatsome theme - WP

Tags: ajax, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I use Flatsome theme and I am using the "add to cart" button SHORTCODE in my page with ajax activated. The redirection to cart after adding the product is disabled so user can stay in my page.
But after the button is clicked the off-canvas-cart window appears. And that is I want to stop.
see: https://www.screencast.com/t/yhmloKy7omp

I want that to stop it becose I am using the Fly Cart plugin to achieve a neat result after the add to cart btton is clicked. See: https://www.screencast.com/t/kh8fuPUT

What I have done so far:
1- I have set the cart to "link only" in Flatsome settings - https://www.screencast.com/t/pcaD4HVXIq (but that setting doesnt seem to affect the add to cart button SHORTCODE)

2- I have managed to hide the cart using css: https://www.screencast.com/t/i2YTMpLjYmqf
but I couldnt remove that top right X close button. And the user must click anywhere on the page to make the page active again and that is not a good experience.
this is the css I used:

```
.off-canvas-cart { display: none !important;}.mfp-bg { display: none!important;}
```

that is pretty much it.
This is the page: http://vendamais.me/site2/criacao-de-logotipo/
and this is the only button I am using to test the shortcode: https://www.screencast.com/t/aFgvqTbkq
(the other buttons are simple buttons ahref style, not woocommerce shortcode)

could you help me on the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

-Set to dowpdown in the configs, then:

```
.nav-dropdown.nav-dropdown-default {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

EDIT:

Add the li and classes to do not loose others dropdowns.

`li.cart-item.has-icon.has-dropdown .nav-dropdown.nav-dropdown-default {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}`